# Python, Flask, SQLAlchemy: cannot import from models

Tags: python, import, sqlalchemy, models

I've got a weird problem.

I am building a Flask app with SQLAlchemy. I have a file with models, namely, models.py. And I have a User model there.

If I open my "views.py" and insert a string

```
import models
```

and then use the User model like

```
u=models.User.query.filter_by(name='John',password='Doe').first()
```

everything works fine.

But if instead of "import models" i put

```
from models import User
```

Python crashes and says:

```
ImportError: cannot import name User
```

how can this be possible?

Answer (score 15):

you most likely have a circular import; your, lets say 'app' module:

```
# app.py
import models
...

def doSomething():
    models.User....
```

but your `models` module also imports `app`

```
import app

class User:
    ...
```

since `models` imports `app`, and `app` imports `models`, python has not finished importing `models` at the point `app` tries to import `models.User`; the `User` class has not been defined (yet).  Either break the cyclic import (make sure `models` doesn't import anything that also imports `models`), or you'll just have to make do with `models.User` instead of the shorter `User` in `app`.

Comment: well, my `views.py` has a line `db=SQLAlchemy(app)`. Next line is `import models`. Then, in the `models.py`, the first line is

Comment: Amazing answer. Thanks, you saved my time :). Keep doing good work.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of

```
from models import User
```

use

```
from models import *
```

Comment: Worked for me for some reason. I would love to know why this works?

Comment: I would like to know the same? Why does import * work?

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are importing the models into `views.py` therefore if you need a class from models, import it from `views.py` and the circular import problem will be resolved.